# Плавная подгрузка содержимого на ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

На серверной части идет парсинг всего инвентаря пользователя из steam. После чего его нужно вывести на страницу по 30 предметов с пагинацией. Имеем два варианта:

1) Либо хранить на сервере все предметы инвентаря, а при нажатии пользователем кнопок пагинации загружать из сервера только 30 предметов. Но при этом способе страницы долго грузятся + некрасивая подгрузка изображений.

2) При открытии страницы загрузить все предметы, и уже посредством js подгружать уже готовые предметы, не тратя время на ожидание ответа от сервера. Но при это способе первоначальная загрузка страницы займет немало времени, особенно если у пользователя тысячи предметов.

Есть ли какие-нибудь альтернативы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете с сервера при старте страницы загрузить первые 30 элементов сразу, а после загрузки страницы в фоне сразу начать подгружать AJAXом оставшиеся страницы (пока пользователь смотрит что пришло остальная часть и загрузится). Это позволяет совместить быстрый показ страницы вначале с быстрой пагинацией.